# Alert View Activity Indicator Display Time

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

Im displaying an activity indicator with an Alert View using:

```
 UIAlertView *Alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading"
                                               message:@"\n"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];   
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); 
[Alert addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[Alert show];    

[Alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

The only thing is it disappears off the screen real quick, I would like to specify how long the alert stays on screen for, say two seconds, rather than the nano second its displayed for now.  Im unsure how to go about/implement this, would I use some sort of NSTimer, if so some advice how to implement this would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Typically, if you are displaying a spinner it is because you are doing work, why not set it to dismiss whenever the work is complete? Or do you really want it to be timed? If you want it to be 2 seconds, then yes you would use an `NSTimer`. I do not see why you would think displaying an alert view and immediately dismissing it would have different results than a millisecond display...

Comment: When I action a tweet from the app using the Twitter framework theres seems to be  a delay of about two to three seconds from the button press to the twitter sheet being displayed.  The Alert View  displays for approx .5s leaving a 2.5s pause. I tried `timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.2/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
` I just get an exception thrown so was trying a work around

Comment: It still seems counter intuitive to have it as a timer. You should not assume the delay you should let the alert view display for the duration of the delay. That is its main purpose. You should be able to place the dismiss in a place after you received the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would go about solving the problem using `NSTimer` and `NSInvocation`. I have not tested it, so might have some trouble with it.

```
UIAlertView *Alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading"
                                               message:@"\n"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];   
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); 
[Alert addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[Alert show];  
NSMethodSignature *mySignature = [UIAlertView instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:)];
NSInvocation *myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:mySignature];
[myInvocation setSelector:@selector(dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:)];
[myInvocation setTarget:Alert];
int buttonIndex = 0;
bool isAnimated = YES;
[myInvocation setArgument:&buttonClicked 
                  atIndex:2];
[myInvocation setArgument:&isAnimated 
                  atIndex:3];
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 
                                          invocation:myInvocation 
                                             repeats:NO];
```

I still do not think this is the best answer to the question though. In most cases you should use the indicator until the work to be done is complete, not based on a time, especially not a time that can change or dependent on other factors.

So the correct answer would be wait until the work is done and at that point dismiss the `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Thanks, the penny has dropped now with the dismissal after action, still finding my way with programming, thanks for your help, I shall do it the correct way as per your advice.